# why do the recycler in netty not restore all the items in the stack?

Tags: java, netty

we know that the item would be pushed to stack or weakOrderQueue ,but what's the purpose of the weakOrderQueue since finally the items in the weakOrderQueue would be transfered to stack.

Answer (score 0):

Aim to reduce conflict if there are many thread concurrently release the handle(DefaultHandle) allocated from the original thread.

Comment: thanks a lot，and now  i understand why that the recycler is designed like that, and it seems that the blog https://www.cnblogs.com/rainy-shurun/p/5213086.html  has an error, the blog said that the object is created or allocated in one thread but is reclaimed in another thread whick would make the pooling meanless. It's wrong, the thread who  allocate the object would reclaim the object, the other thread only helps to recycle。Am I right?

Comment: 是的，另一个线程释放的时候如果发现不是从自己这里分配的话，会放在分配线程的那个weakqueue里的。

Comment: and I find something weired, if the object allocated in the thread A and we try to reclaim it in another two threads, it would be successful,  and I know it would be recycled only once due to the checking of recycleId and lastRecycleId,but the object would  exist in two weakOrderQueue and consume double space which would reduce the capacity of the pooling.  I just write in  English to improve my pool English,thanks my brother

Comment: You can check the io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf#release(int) method.If multithread release the same buffer parallelly,only one can succeed.

Comment: thanks, now I understand that one object could be recycled serveral times and since be popped the same times(don't consider in the ratiomask);   And another question that I don't know why  we need ratioMask which is used  in the transfer method,why do we  drop objects in the weakOrderQueue when we don't have any object in the stack,

Comment: HandleRecycleCount is recorded in the src Stack,and every 8th is recycled by default,so it's src thread responsibility to drop the objects.

Comment: i know that,i mean why do we have to drop the objects

Comment: Netty has a comment on the io.netty.util.Recycler#RATIO,said ```By default we allow one push to a Recycler for each 8th try on handles that were never recycled before.This should help to slowly increase the capacity of the recycler while not be too sensitive to allocation
 bursts.```

Comment: sorry，I readed the comment ever before but the comment is still puzzling for me, in another word , what would happen if we don't have the ratio,and we don't drop the object as long as there is idle space.